# Parsing GPS data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, geospatial

Recently I sent this code snippet as CV attachment and I got simple answer - this code smells and we employ another developer.

I'm new to RoR, so guys can you give me directions to refactor this code and make it amazing?

This code is for parsing uploaded file with GPS data in 3 supported formats CSV, xml, tes (binary). And "answering to controller and other model calls".

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum kind: [ :skydive, :base ]

  attr_accessor :trackfile, :track_index

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wingsuit

  has_one :event_track

  has_many :tracksegments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :points, :through => :tracksegments
  before_save :parse_file

  def calc_results(range_from, range_to)

    fl_time = 0
    distance = 0
    speed = 0

    is_first = true
    prev_point = nil

    track_points = get_track_data
    track_points.each do |current_point|

      is_last = true

      if current_point[:elevation] <= range_from && current_point[:elevation] >= range_to

        is_last = false

        if is_first
          is_first = false
          if current_point[:elevation] != range_from && prev_point.present?
            elev_diff = range_from - current_point[:elevation]
            k = elev_diff / current_point[:elevation_diff]
            fl_time = (current_point[:fl_time] * k).round(1)
            distance = (current_point[:distance] * k).round(0)
          end
          next
        end

        fl_time += current_point[:fl_time].round(1)
        distance += current_point[:distance].round(0)

      end

      if is_last && fl_time > 0
        if current_point[:elevation] <= range_to
          elev_diff = prev_point[:elevation] - range_to
          k = elev_diff / current_point[:elevation_diff]
          fl_time += (current_point[:fl_time] * k).round(1)
          distance += (current_point[:distance] * k).round(0)
        end
        break
      end

      prev_point = current_point

    end

    fl_time = fl_time.round(1)
    distance = distance.round(0)
    speed = (distance / fl_time * 3.6).round(0)

    {:fl_time => fl_time,
     :distance => distance,
     :speed => speed}

  end

  def get_charts_data
    get_track_data.to_json.html_safe
  end

  def get_earth_data
    data = get_track_data.map { |x| {:latitude => x[:latitude],
                                      :longitude => x[:longitude],
                                      :h_speed => x[:h_speed],
                                      :elevation => x[:abs_altitude].nil? ? x[:elevation] : x[:abs_altitude]} }
    data.to_json.html_safe
  end

  def get_max_height
    get_track_data.max_by{ |x| x[:elevation] }[:elevation].round
  end

  def get_min_height
    get_track_data.min_by{ |x| x[:elevation] }[:elevation].round
  end

  def get_heights_data
    get_track_data(false).map{ |p| [p[:fl_time_abs], p[:elevation]] }.to_json.html_safe
  end

  def get_duration
    get_track_data(false).map{ |p| p[:fl_time] }.inject(0, :+)
  end

  def presentation
    "#{self.name} | #{self.suit} | #{self.comment}"
  end

  private

  def get_track_data(trim = true)
    arr = []
    prev_point = nil
    fl_time = 0

    points.each do |point|
      if prev_point != nil
        fl_time += point.point_created_at - prev_point.point_created_at
        arr << {:fl_time => point.point_created_at - prev_point.point_created_at,
                :fl_time_abs => fl_time,
                :elevation_diff => (prev_point.elevation - point.elevation).round(2),
                :elevation => point.elevation.round(2),
                :abs_altitude => point.abs_altitude,
                :latitude => point.latitude,
                :longitude => point.longitude,
                :distance => point.distance.to_i,
                :h_speed => point.h_speed.round(2),
                :v_speed => point.v_speed.round(2),
                :glrat => (point.h_speed.round(2) / point.v_speed.round(2)).round(2)
        }
      end
      prev_point = point
    end

    if trim
      if ff_start.present?
        arr = arr.drop_while{ |x| x[:fl_time_abs] < ff_start}
      end
      if ff_end.present? && ff_end > 0 && (ff_start.blank? || ff_end > ff_start)
        arr.reverse!
        arr = arr.drop_while{ |x| x[:fl_time_abs] > ff_end}
        arr.reverse!
      end
    end

    arr

  end

  def parse_file

    track_points = []

    if self.new_record?
      if trackfile[:ext] == '.csv'
        track_points = parse_csv trackfile[:data]
      elsif trackfile[:ext] == '.gpx'
        doc = Nokogiri::XML(trackfile[:data])
        track_points = parse_xml doc, track_index
      elsif trackfile[:ext] == '.tes'
        track_points = parse_tes trackfile[:data]
      end

      if track_points.empty?
        return false
      else
        processed_track_points = process_track_points track_points
        record_track_points processed_track_points
      end
    end

  end

  def get_file_format(header)

    headers_hash = {:flysight => %w(time lat lon hMSL velN velE velD hAcc vAcc sAcc gpsFix numSV),
                    :flysight2 => %w(time lat lon hMSL velN velE velD hAcc vAcc sAcc heading cAcc gpsFix numSV),
                    :columbusV900 => %w(INDEX TAG DATE TIME LATITUDE\ N/S LONGITUDE\ E/W HEIGHT SPEED HEADING VOX)}

    headers_hash.select{|key,hash| hash == header}.keys[0]

  end

  def parse_csv_row(row, format)

    if (format == :flysight) || (format ==:flysight2)

      return nil if (row[1].to_f == 0.0 || row[8].to_i > 70)

      {:latitude => row[1].to_f,
       :longitude => row[2].to_f,
       :elevation => row[3].to_f,
       :abs_altitude => row[3].to_f,
       :point_created_at => row[0].to_s}

    elsif format == :columbusV900

      return nil if row[6].to_f == 0.0

      {:latitude => (row[4][0..(row[4].length-2)] * (row[4][row[4].length-1] == 'N' ? 1 : -1)).to_f,
        :longitude => (row[5][0..(row[5].length-2)] * (row[5][row[5].length-1] == 'E' ? 1 : 01)).to_f,
        :elevation => row[6].to_f,
        :abs_altitude => row[6].to_f,
        :point_created_at => DateTime.strptime('20' + row[2].to_s + 'T' + row[3].to_s, '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')}

    else
      nil
    end

  end

  def parse_csv(doc)

    require 'csv'

    track_points = []
    file_format = nil

    CSV.parse(doc) do |row|

      if file_format == nil
        file_format = get_file_format row
        if file_format == nil
          break
        end
        next
      end

      track_points << parse_csv_row(row, file_format)
    end

    track_points.compact!
  end

  # TODO: refactor that
  def parse_xml(doc, track_index)

    track_points = []

    index = 0

    doc.root.elements.each do |trks|
      # Обход всех треков в файле и разбор выбранного пользователем
      if trks.node_name.eql? 'trk'
        if index.to_i == track_index.to_i
          # Если это выбранный трек - обход всех сегментов
          trks.elements.each do |trkseg|
            if trkseg.node_name.eql? 'trkseg'
              # Обход всех точек сегмента и формирование массива хэшей
              trkseg.elements.each do |trpoint|
                point_hash = {:latitude => trpoint.attr('lat').to_f, :longitude => trpoint.attr('lon').to_f}
                trpoint.elements.each do |node|
                  point_hash[:elevation] = node.text.to_f if node.name.eql? 'ele'
                  point_hash[:abs_altitude] = node.text.to_f if node.name.eql? 'ele'
                  point_hash[:point_created_at] = node.text.to_s if node.name.eql? 'time'
                end
                track_points << point_hash
              end
            end
          end
          break
        end
        index += 1
      end
    end

    track_points

  end

  def parse_tes(doc)
    unpacked_string = doc.unpack('SLLLS' * (doc.length / 16))
    track_points = []

    for x in 0..(unpacked_string.count / 5 - 1)
      track_points << {:latitude => unpacked_string[x * 5 + 2] / 1.0e7,
                  :longitude => unpacked_string[x * 5 + 3] / 1.0e7,
                  :elevation => unpacked_string[x * 5 + 4],
                  :point_created_at => unpacked_string[x * 5 + 1]}
    end

    track_points.each do |x|
      binarydate = x[:point_created_at].to_s(2).reverse

      year = "20#{binarydate[26..31].reverse.to_i(2).to_s}"
      month = binarydate[22..25].reverse.to_i(2)
      month = month < 10 ? "0#{month}" : month.to_s
      day = binarydate[17..21].reverse.to_i(2).to_s
      hour = binarydate[12..16].reverse.to_i(2).to_s
      min = binarydate[6..11].reverse.to_i(2).to_s
      sec = binarydate[0..5].reverse.to_i(2).to_s

      x[:point_created_at] = "#{year}-#{month}-#{day}T#{hour}:#{min}:#{sec}"
    end
  end

  def calc_distance(a, b)
    rad_per_deg = Math::PI/180  # PI / 180
    rkm = 6371                  # Радиус земли в километрах
    rm = rkm * 1000

    dlon_rad = (b[1]-a[1]) * rad_per_deg
    dlat_rad = (b[0]-a[0]) * rad_per_deg

    lat1_rad, lon1_rad = a.map! {|i| i * rad_per_deg }
    lat2_rad, lon2_rad = b.map! {|i| i * rad_per_deg }

    a = Math.sin(dlat_rad/2)**2 + Math.cos(lat1_rad) * Math.cos(lat2_rad) * Math.sin(dlon_rad/2)**2
    c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a))

    rm * c # Расстояние в метрах
  end

  def process_track_points(track_points)

    # Пока не придумал что делать с 5 Гц и 10 Гц файлами - оставляю только первую запись по дате создания
    track_points.uniq!{ |x| DateTime.strptime(x[:point_created_at], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') }

    min_h = track_points.min_by{ |x| x[:elevation] }[:elevation]
    # Уменьшим высоту во всех точках на минимальную. (корректировка относительно уровня земли)
    track_points.each do |x|
      x[:elevation] -= min_h
    end

    min_h = track_points.min_by{ |x| x[:elevation] }[:elevation]
    max_h = track_points.max_by{ |x| x[:elevation] }[:elevation]

    # Расчет дистанции и времени полета
    fl_time = 0

    track_points.each_index do |i|
      point = track_points[i]
      point[:distance] = 0 if i == 0
      if i > 0
        prev_point = track_points.at(i-1)

        datetime_1 = DateTime.strptime(point[:point_created_at], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
        datetime_2 = DateTime.strptime(prev_point[:point_created_at], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
        fl_time_diff = (datetime_1 - datetime_2) * 1.days
        fl_time += fl_time_diff

        point[:distance] = calc_distance [prev_point[:latitude], prev_point[:longitude]], [point[:latitude], point[:longitude]]
        point[:h_speed] = point[:distance] / fl_time_diff * 3.6
        point[:v_speed] = (prev_point[:elevation] - point[:elevation]) / fl_time_diff * 3.6
      end
      point[:fl_time] = fl_time
    end

    # Медианный фильтр для расстояния и высоты
    track_points.each_index do |i|

      point = track_points[i]

      median_start = [0, i-1].max
      median_end  = [track_points.count-1, i+1].min

      median_points = [track_points[median_start], point, track_points[median_end]]
      point[:distance]  = median_points.map { |x| x[:distance] }.sort[1]
      point[:elevation] = median_points.map { |x| x[:elevation] }.sort[1]
      point[:h_speed]   = median_points.map { |x| x[:h_speed] || 0 }.sort[1]
      point[:v_speed]   = median_points.map { |x| x[:v_speed] || 0 }.sort[1]

    end

    self.ff_start = 0
    self.ff_end = fl_time

    # Развернем массив и найдем точку после достижения максимальной высоты и набору скорости в 25 км/ч
    track_points.reverse!
    start_point = track_points.detect { |x| x[:elevation] >= (max_h - 15) }
    self.ff_start = start_point[:fl_time] if start_point.present?

    track_points.reverse!
    start_point = track_points.detect { |x| (x[:fl_time] > self.ff_start && x[:v_speed] > 25) }
    self.ff_start = start_point[:fl_time] if start_point.present?

    # Найдем первую точку ниже минимума (предполагаю Земли) + 50 метров
    end_point = track_points.detect { |x| x[:elevation] < (min_h + 50) }
    self.ff_end = end_point[:fl_time] if end_point.present?

    track_points

  end

  def record_track_points(track_points)

    if track_points.count < 10
      return false
    end

    trkseg = Tracksegment.new

    track_points.each do |trkpoint|
      trkseg.points << Point.new(trkpoint)
    end

    self.tracksegments << trkseg

  end

end
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: This code is for parsing uploaded file with GPS data in 3 supported formats CSV, xml, tes (binary). And "answering to controller and other model calls"

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context *to your question*. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the spectrum of what-a-class-is-responsible-for, the `Track` sits closer to the Swiss Army knife end than the grapefruit fork end. Though both are legitimate approaches, Swiss Army knives typically require justification. Otherwise, some people consider refactoring appropriate.

For example, the CSV, XML, TES  parsers could each live in their own class, and each of those classes could inherit from a track_parser class. If there's a bug in CSV parsing, having XML parsing code in the file is likely to be noise rather than useful...particularly as an application grows larger. Likewise, if parsing in general needs to change, then a `track_parser`class provides a place to document/implement/enforce the change.

A few small items that jump out:

- Magic Number: 3.6 on lines 66, 340 and 341.
- Like any mutable operation, calling `reverse!` on a data structure is not considered functional style programming and Ruby programmers tend toward a functional programming style. Calling it twice on the same array [Lines 137/139 and 366/370] suggests walking the array with a decreasing index as an alternative.
- Use of `if` rather than `case...when...` in `parse_file` is not idomatic Ruby.
- `track_points` appears 46 times in the code and has structure, should it be a class?

Comment: Thanks for that great answer. Only two questions: 1. should I place classes in separate files? (i.e. track_parser.rb, csv_parser.rb, etc) 2. Where (which folder) should I place these files in RoR application?

Comment: 3.6 is value to convert meters/sec to kilometers/hour. Should I declare it somewhere as a constant? If yes - what is the best place for it?

Comment: @AleksandrK. **1:** This StackOverflow question contains some thoughtful links on breaking up fat modules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241527/splitting-a-class-into-multiple-files-in-ruby-on-rails **2:** I'd consider a velocity class with a to_kmh method. But that's just me.