# Class for median filter

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby, later I asked about ways to refactor code ([Parsing GPS data](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67538/parsing-gps-data)), one man gave me direction, so I made class for Median filter and it will be great to read review for my work.

What guys are you thinking about it? Is it still smells?

```
class MedianFilter
  attr_accessor :step

  def initialize(step, keys)

    raise ArgumentError.new('Step must be odd and higher than 3') if step < 3 && step % 2 != 1
    raise ArgumentError.new('Keys must be array of symbols') unless keys.kind_of?(Array) && keys.count > 0

    @step = step
    @keys = keys

  end

  def filter(param_values)
    process_values param_values.clone
  end

  def filter!(param_values)
    process_values param_values
  end

  private

  def process_values(values)

    half_step = (@step - 1) / 2

    values.each_index do |i|

      item = values[i]

      median_points = [ values[ [0, i - half_step].max ],
                        item,
                        values[ [values.count - 1, i + half_step].min ] ]

      @keys.each do |key|
        item[key] = median_points.map { |x| x[key] || 0 }.sort[half_step]
      end

    end

    values

  end

end
```

Comment: Did you ask about it here? Do you mind adding a link to the original question for context?

Comment: @RubberDuck, fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has some bad side-effects. There's no real difference between `filter` and `filter!` since they both modify the input values directly.

It seems that your input is something like:

```
[{foo: 2}, {foo: 80}, {foo: 6}, {foo: 3}]
```

in other words, an array of hashes.

When you call `filter`, you duplicate the *array* - but the hash objects are still the same objects. So when you calculate the median, and set `item[key] = ...`, you're modifying the same hash objects. Duplicating the array has no real effect; you're not modifying the array itself, only the objects inside the array. And those objects are the same even if you duplicate the array.

An example:

```
filter = MedianFilter.new(3, [:foo])
original = [{foo: 2}, {foo: 80}, {foo: 6}, {foo: 3}]

modified = filter.filter(values)

modified # => [{:foo=>2}, {:foo=>6}, {:foo=>6}, {:foo=>3}]
original # => [{:foo=>2}, {:foo=>6}, {:foo=>6}, {:foo=>3}]
```

In the example, `modified` is a different array object than `original`, but the *contents* of both arrays have been changed. In order words: Your `filter` method has side-effects.

And I doubt that's what you want.

Anyway, about the code:

- Another bug: Your exception says that `step` "must be odd *and* higher than 3", but that's not what you actually check. You code checks whether `step` is *below* 3 and *even*. So I can pass in 4 and not get an error, even though it's an even number. Or I can pass in -3 and not get an error, even though is less than 3.
  Your error message is also a little misleading. It says "*higher than* 3" when it fact it can be 3.
- You check of `keys` only checks for a non-empty array - it doesn't check that the array only contains symbols. I could pass in `["foo", 42, Date.new]` without the initializer raising an error.
- There are a few built-in methods that would make the checks more idiomatic and readable. For instance, `step % 2 != 1` can be written as `step.even?`, and `keys.count > 0` can be written as `!keys.empty?`
- I'd probably rename `step` to `window_size`, since I think that's a better name. Or you might simply redefine it as the number of neighbors to include - i.e. what you currently call `half_step`.
- I'd simply skip the `keys` argument, and instead provide the input data in a different way. It would keep this class simple and generic.
- I'm not sure this actually needs to be a class, since it doesn't really need to maintain state. It could just be a method.
- As for the `process` method, you can use `each_cons` to get the "windows" you want to find the median for. You just need to pad the array a little. Here's a simplified example:

  ```
  # example input
  values = [2, 80, 6, 3]
  window_size = 3
  neighbors = (window_size / 2).floor

  # create an array with extra elements at the start and end
  temp = ([values.first] * neighbors) + values + ([values.last] * neighbors)

  # calculate medians
  medians = temp.each_cons(window_size).map { |window| window.sort[neighbors] }

  medians # => [2, 6, 6, 3]
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much for that great and helpful answer. I have question about 'it could be a method' - should I put this method in module or in class that using it?

Comment: In the previous question (link in post) I got answer that parsers should be the classes TrackParser > GPXParser, TESParser, etc. Could you please write your opinion about it?

Comment: @AleksandrK. Yes, the method should still be in a class somewhere - it should be where you need it. And you got some good advice in your last post; the parsers probably should be separate classes. Their job is to take a file, and return an array of points that follow a standard format. However, the median filtering is something that would happen _after_ you've parsed the files, so that probably shouldn't be in the separate parser classes, but somewhere else.

Comment: I've thought a lot about your snippet and modify it for my purposes, here what I've done: `temp.each_cons(window_size).map do |window|
      keys.each do |key|
        window[neighbors][key] = window.map { |x| x[key] }.sort[neighbors]
      end
      window[neighbors]
    end` could you please write your opinion?

Comment: @AleksandrK. Looks OK to me